# How to create a socket from a particular InetSocketAddress?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a list of InetSocketAddress and I want to create a socket to that address but not sure how. I am a beginner to network programming!
This is what I have done, but not sure if my logic is correct, can you help please?

```
InetSocketAddress inetAddress =routingTable.get(targetNode);//Hashmap of InetSocketAddress
ServerSocket server= new ServerSocket();
server.bind(inetAddress);
Socket socket=server.accept();
```

Comment: Do you want to listen for incoming connections, or initiate an outgoing connection? What problem are you having with the code you've written? If it doesn't work, what's not working? See [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) in the help center for guidance on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you've done it correctly, by binding the inetaddress you are setting a socket to that address. So in short test it but that is the correct procedure.

By calling accept any incoming connect request to that address will be correctly received and you now have access to that client.